# Unable to run VueJS SPA with Spring Boot

Tags: node.js, spring, spring-boot, webpack, vue.js

I have VueJS single page appication which I want to move to the Spring Boot project and run it in the production environment. With `npm run build` I genereted these files:

```
Hash: 0e5605ab6a3adbae5bc3
Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 34203ms
                                                  Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
                  static/js/app.a8c2e3befee9add63a47.js    67.9 kB       1  [emitted]         app
                             static/img/bg3.7e9308f.jpg     191 kB          [emitted]
    static/img/glyphicons-halflings-regular.8988968.svg     109 kB          [emitted]
static/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a.woff2      18 kB          [emitted]
  static/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.f4769f9.eot    20.1 kB          [emitted]
  static/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.e18bbf6.ttf    45.4 kB          [emitted]
                 static/fonts/element-icons.6f0a763.ttf      11 kB          [emitted]
               static/js/vendor.b870d414939280bd7c3a.js     1.1 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
 static/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.fa27723.woff    23.4 kB          [emitted]
             static/js/manifest.58a976c7eeb4e639b033.js    1.49 kB       2  [emitted]         manifest
    static/css/app.8dfb1913ee552ff55ff81ea142c3f782.css     443 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]  app
static/css/app.8dfb1913ee552ff55ff81ea142c3f782.css.map     623 kB          [emitted]
           static/js/vendor.b870d414939280bd7c3a.js.map    3.99 MB       0  [emitted]         vendor
              static/js/app.a8c2e3befee9add63a47.js.map     267 kB       1  [emitted]         app
         static/js/manifest.58a976c7eeb4e639b033.js.map     7.8 kB       2  [emitted]         manifest
                                             index.html  704 bytes          [emitted]

  Build complete.
```

And I copied them to `/resources/static` folder. When I run Spring Boot project I'm able to open `index.html` file, but all of the related resources like js, css and img files returns `404 Not Found Exception`. I can't even load them with direct link in the browser.

This is very strange, because when I copy and paste, for example, `static/css/app.8dfb1913ee552ff55ff81ea142c3f782.css` file and change only one digit in the name, I'm able to load it with the browser.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the coping files to the resource folder is very fragile in Spring Boot. With those exactly steps I was able to run my project:

1. Stop application (the embeded Tomcat)
2. Delete all files in `/resources/static` folder
3. Copy new html/css/js/img files
4. Clean and Build the project
5. Run the application